# IBM Cloud Node-Red error (APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 1)

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

Good day to all. I have an app in the IBM Cloud running with using the Internet of Things Platform Starter. Since I installed a resource, i.e. API Connect, and made the connection to my app, my app is then not running anymore.

Even I deleted the API Connect and disconnected with my app, my app still cannot work anymore. But the design and information in this app are important for me.

The following is the log for running my app.

> 2018-02-22T16:24:18.91+0800 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
> 2018-02-22T16:24:21.13+0800 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:46.68+0800 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR /home/vcap/app/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js:3
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR const assign = require('./util/assign')
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ^^^^^
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at require (module.js:384:17)
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object. (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/node-red/red.js:26:10)
>     
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.93+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.96+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:47.97+0800 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:48.02+0800 [CELL/0] OUT Stopping instance f426c44a-11b6-4373-453d-577f
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:48.02+0800 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:50.77+0800 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:54.02+0800 [API/4] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
>      
> 2018-02-22T16:24:54.15+0800 [API/4] OUT App instance exited with guid 54f30301-ef43-4476-9ba6-261ca1c47aae payload: {"instance"=>"f426c44a-11b6-4373-453d-577f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 1", "crash_count"=>67, "crash_timestamp"=>1519287887997896126, "version"=>"8915be08-78b2-4717-808c-aea8b227afe4"}

Please help me and many thanks to you all.

Comment: Put the error description in your question as text.

Comment: What version of the NodeJS engine is your instance running?

Comment: Internet of Things Platform Starter version 0.7.0 includes the SDK for Node.js

Comment: Yes, but what version of NodeJS is it using. It looks like you have installed a Node that needs a newer version of NodeJS than is being used